# Angular Universal serve:ssr Server Side Render Builder

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering, angular-builder, angular-devkit

I want ssr on dev mode to reproduce production server render during development, And i can't setup ssr and ng serve both running because of live reload will not work on ssr port.

Server side render not working on development mode yet with hot reload
the only serve builder is

```
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"
```

this builder not serving with server side render for development build

create an Angular CLI builder that can provide development server that builds in watch mode and live reloads whenever the project changes like `ng serve` with this builder as part of the @nguniversal schematics.

Github issues:

- https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1276
  https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1202

Comment: For what reason You need to SSR work on dev mode ? Why You cannot set up SSR and dev on regular `ng serve` ?

Comment: SSR on dev mode to reproduce same behavior for server render on production,
Cannot setup `ssr` and `ng serve` because of live reload will not work on ssr port